# MSTest: Unit testing - Input file not found ... vsmdi

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, c#-2.0, mstest

I have a project that I would like to add a unit test. There are other unit tests in the project that were written by previous developers. I am tying to test an object that reads and XML file into an object. To do this I choose the test project and add a unit test and then select the class for which I want the unit test. The stubbed out class gets auto-generated and I can successfully compile the project but when I run I get the error

> Input file not found: C:\Blah\Blah\Blah\Blah\MYPROJECTNAME.vsmdi.

I tried checking out all the files in the test solution and recreating the unit test but I still get the same error

For your info:

1. There are no vsmdi files in my project
2. Running Visual Studio 2010
3. TFS 2010
4. Targeting the .NET 2.0 runtime (can't go to 4.0 due to management restriction)
5. This is a console application
6. Using MSTest

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks... Orin

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem. What I did:

1. Closed solution and Visual Studio
2. Removed 'partial read only' from the folder with project
3. Open VS again and launched tests

I still have that message in "Output Test" window, but tests are executable.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue for you, I would suggest checking to see that you have write permissions on the directory where its trying to create the VSMDI file both locally and on the build server, if you're running a server build.  If I recall correctly, you'll encounter this message if VS cannot create the VSMDI file.